# what is a real pte (as opposed to migration pte in NUMA)

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, numa

As I am reading the NUMA documentation in Linux and thru the source code, I can see that they replace the migration entry, which is a PTE of type `SWP_MIGRATION_WRITE` or `SWP_MIGRATION_READ`, with normal PTE. Well, what is a **Normal** PTE? What kind of information is should contain?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics of those flags, it sounds like `SWP_MIGRATION_WRITE` and `SWP_MIGRATION_READ` might describe the state of a PTE struct or page as it's being migrated from one NUMA domain to another.  In that context, a "normal" PTE might be one that's not in the process of migration.  Does that sound right?

As for what information a PTE contains, it describes the physical base address of a page and some flags about the accessibility and state of it.  See http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory/.